# Defining first event: Already present or newly occured?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have longitudinal data that is stored in different tables for each year and want to verify if an `event` 'T' is already present or has newly occured and derive the `eventdate`

Example data

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JteJjhwy)

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2010 (
    ID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    Event CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_2011 (
    ID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    Event CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_2012 (
    ID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    Event CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_2013 (
    ID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    Event CHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_2014 (
    ID INT,
    EventDate DATE,
    Event CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Table_2010 (ID, EventDate, Event) VALUES
    (1, '2010-01-01', 'U'),
    (1, '2010-02-01', 'U'),
    (2, '2010-01-15', 'T'),
    (2, '2010-02-15', 'V');

INSERT INTO Table_2011 (ID, EventDate, Event) VALUES
    (1, '2011-01-01', 'T'),
    (1, '2011-02-01', 'V'),
    (2, '2011-01-15', 'X'),
    (2, '2011-02-15', 'Z'),
    (2, '2011-03-01', 'T'),
    (3, '2011-02-20', 'T'),
    (3, '2011-03-30', 'Z');

INSERT INTO Table_2012 (ID, EventDate, Event) VALUES
    (1, '2012-01-01', 'U'),
    (1, '2012-02-01', 'T'),
    (2, '2012-01-15', 'T'),
    (2, '2012-02-15', 'Z'),
    (2, '2012-03-01', 'Z');

INSERT INTO Table_2013 (ID, EventDate, Event) VALUES
    (1, '2013-01-01', 'T'),
    (1, '2013-02-01', 'Z'),
    (2, '2013-01-15', 'T'),
    (2, '2013-02-15', 'Y');

INSERT INTO Table_2014 (ID, EventDate, Event) VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01', 'Z'),
    (1, '2014-02-01', 'T'),
    (2, '2014-01-15', 'T'),
    (2, '2014-02-15', 'X'),
    (2, '2014-03-01', 'Z');
```

So my go-to approach would be as follows:

```
SELECT ID, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'T' THEN EventDate END) AS T_StartDate
FROM (
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2010
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2011
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2012
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2013
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2014
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
) AS AllEvents
GROUP BY ID;
```

The problem is that i do not know what happened before the first entry of an `ID`.

Consider `ID` 1 and 2 which are present in `Table_2010`:

`ID` 1 does not have the `event` in 2010 but in 2011. Because the `event` did not happen before 2011 i would classify this event as newly occured whereas `ID` 2 already had the event in 2010 and needs to be considered as already present.

In my opinion i need to verify if there is an event-free period before the first occurence.

How can i implement that?

Expected output (dummy coded 1: Yes; 0: No)

| ID | Eventdate | Newly occured |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2010-01-15 | 0 |
| 3 | 2011-02-20 | 0 |

Comment: has the first event not the lowest date?

Comment: Can you show the expected output ?

Comment: Yes, but if the `event` is present within the first data entries of an `ID` without existing prior data entries my go-to approach also derives the `eventdate` and i can not distinguish between already present or newly occured because i did not verify if there is an `event`-free time before the first `event`

Comment: @NenadZivkovic i added the expected output. thank you for mentioning.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to understand the logic, but just can't get it. How is 3 not newly occurred, when it first appears in 2011? How does tables 2012-2014 affect the calculation? What is the point of view/time from which to decide something is new?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Because ID 3 first appears in Table_2011 with event T. ID3 is not present In Table_2010. To consider this as a new event ID 3 needs to be present in Table_2010 WITHOUT event T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might still need some work on, as I still don't understand how later years affect math, but based on explanations so far, maybe something in this direction can work?

I added one mid step to better explain:

```
WITH CTE_T_Events AS
(
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2010
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2011
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2012
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2013
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2014
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
), 
CTE_Group AS
(
    SELECT ID, MIN(EventDate) AS T_StartDate 
    , CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_2010 x WHERE x.ID = t.ID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Exists2010
    , CASE WHEN Exists (SELECT * FROM Table_2010 y WHERE y.ID = t.ID AND y.Event ='T') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as T_Exists2010
    FROM CTE_T_Events t
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
, CASE WHEN Exists2010 = 1 AND T_Exists2010 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as NewlyOccured
FROM CTE_Group
```

[Fiddle with and without 3-X](https://dbfiddle.uk/8iWD5mA1)

Comment: Works fine - thank you for your effort! I only added later years to try out a few things later. IDs can be added, dropped and be present for arbitrary periods within the longitudinal data.

Answer (score 0):

The With clause is in this case needed as i also wanted to have the minimum ID, to determine if it is the evenet

But we don't recommend having multiple tables of identical design, as long there are not really good causes for that.

```
WITH AllEvents as (    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2010
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2011
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2012
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2013
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2014
    WHERE Event IN ('T')
)
SELECT ID, MIN(event) event, 
    MIN(EventDate ) AS T_StartDate,
 CASE WHEN ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM AllEvents) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END new_evenbnt6
FROM AllEvents


GROUP BY ID
```

| ID | event | T_StartDate | new_evenbnt6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | 2011-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | T | 2010-01-15 | 0 |
| 3 | T | 2011-02-20 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AlO7hTom)

For your new requirement you need to add also AllEvents

```
WITH AllEvents as (    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2010
    WHERE Event IN ('T','X')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2011
    WHERE Event IN ('T','X')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2012
    WHERE Event IN ('T','X')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2013
    WHERE Event IN ('T','X')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, EventDate, Event
    FROM Table_2014
    WHERE Event IN ('T','X')
)
SELECT ID,  event,
    MIN(EventDate ) AS T_StartDate,
 CASE WHEN Year(MIN(EventDate )) = (SELECT Year(MIN(EventDate )) FROM AllEvents) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END new_evenbnt6
FROM AllEvents


GROUP BY ID, event
```

| ID | event | T_StartDate | new_evenbnt6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | 2011-01-01 | 0 |
| 2 | T | 2010-01-15 | 1 |
| 3 | T | 2011-02-20 | 0 |
| 2 | X | 2011-01-15 | 0 |
| 3 | X | 2010-02-15 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T7z3y38S)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that! Is it possible to have a query that can adapt to changes? For instance if I insert `ID` 3 in `Table_2010` WITHOUT an event the query needs to classify as new-event. https://dbfiddle.uk/BcwWSSJc

Comment: i am sorry i can't follow you, you selected only Event T, so event X can't appear in the outer SELECT, you want all new event for multiple events?

Comment: Consider ID 3 which is now present in Table_2010 WITHOUT the event and present in Table_2011 WITH the event. So ID 3 needs to be considered as a new event like ID 1.

Comment: you can only have this when you change the query see https://dbfiddle.uk/Ria1rkIs